# Developing an automated software deployment program through Samba or Active Directory

Tags: windows, deployment, samba

I'm a web developer that needs to build a piece of software for my local office of about 20-30  Windows computers. It needs to automatically and silently run software updates and deployments on all computers.

The Windows computers run on a local network. I'm not sure where to start putting my hands on with something like this... I'm an experienced programmer, just need the right direction on what to read.

I know each Windows client has a Samba server, and also we're using Active Directory, but I'm not sure how that works.

How would I go about starting developing this? I'm sure there's Windows APIs for samba file transfers, but I also need to know about documentation on silently installing the .exe or whatever, and also I need APIs to know the applications running on the client to understand if they need to be updated.

Where's all these APIs?

Comment: Looks like a question for serverfault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [wpkg.org](http://www.wpkg.org/). It's license is GPL. It runs on Samba in an Active Directory. See also their [feature overview](http://www.wpkg.org/WPKG_overview).

I mentioned Samba only because you also did so. Though your exact words read: *'I know each Windows client has a Samba server [....] though I'm not sure how that works.'*

In case you meant that each ***Windows client has access to a Samba server***, my answer may be contributing to help you.

In case you thought your ***Windows clients are running Samba*** themselves, this is impossible (but my answer may help to clarify a few things nevertheless).

Here's why:

- Samba is an implementation of the Microsoft SMB stack of networking protocols for Unix-oid operating systems.
- SMB is what all Windows computers use natively.

Answer (score 0):

why exactly you want do develop this application 
there is a Microsoft product responsible for this thing . it is called SUS server